# canonical orthonormal basis of a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: harmonic-analysis

currently I am reading Ole Christensen's An Introduction to Frames and Riesz Bases.

what is canonical orthonormal basis of a finite dimensional vector space and how to calculate .

thanks in advance.

Comment: For a general finite dimensional space there is no such thing. For $\Bbb{R}^n$ what is meant is the basis $(e_i)_i$, where $e_1 =(1,0,\dots,0), e_2 =(0,1,0,\dots,0)$, etc.

Comment: What is the definition in general case. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, for a general finite dimensional vector space, it does not make sense to speak of a *canonical* orthonormal basis. Where in the book is this notion used?